# Matching variables with url parameters in nodejs & express

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

This is really just a conceptual question as I am a beginner to nodejs and express. So basically I would like to have a route that is something along these lines:

Controller

```
app.get('/explore/:qID?', siteRoutes.explore);
```

Routes

```
exports.explore = function(req, res){
...
```

};

So the way I wold like to have this happen is to pass a variable called qID to the controller using an ajax call. Is there any way that I can take that variable and inject it into the route? My wording is confusing, probably. Basically I want to be able to go to url.com/explore/5 and have that display the corresponding question (qID). Is this the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at req.param in the express docs.

http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.param

basically your route will look like this

```
app.get('/explore/:qID', siteRoutes.explore);
```

You can access the qID like this:

> var qID = req.param('qID');

Comment: I guess what I was wondering is how do I pass that app.get the qID in the first place? Is that done through AJAX?

Comment: Messed around with this for a while and you were totally right! :) I was using 'req.params' for the past 20 minutes and I could not figure out why it wasnt working. Changed it to 'req.param' and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot, @Mike Bennett

Comment: The documentation on `:label`, even more on `:optionalLabel?` is rather implicit (only ‘mentioned’) on http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.route. Or is there another place with more documentation on (what I would call) request parameter matching?